# reading two text files directories in java and combining their content

Tags: java, readfile

im new to java and i want to write a program that gets two directories as an input, the directories contain .txt files. the program should read files from both directories and combine the content of those with the same name into a new file and put in a new directory.

the files contain DNA sequences 
i would appreciate any help with hints or ways on how to achieve this.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take some time to read the [tour], and [ask].  This question is too broad. Depending on the OS, you can probably just do this with a script.

Answer (score 0):

You can open two files simultaneously in java using two different objects.
Now store all the desired contents from file  1 into string variable.
Do the same with second file(create the two diff string).
And then merge the data  under new string variable.Now contents of the newest string can be transfered into new file